# How to remove database snapshot based on timing, and user ID using Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have an application which updates the location of the user, and the time it was updated, There's a bug that can be solved only on server-sided, which in my case Firebase

The bug is, if user lost connection while having my app opened, he'll end up having his location stored in the database

I've tried deploying Cloud Function, where every 2 hours, I remove userID, but it doesn't really remove the datasnapshot

So I wonder how to get userid and remove that bugged datasnapshot each 2 hours

1PQq... --> userID
rest is known

[image: datasnapshot example]

Here's the code i used

```
    exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref('/driversAvailable/{uid}')
.onWrite(event => {
  var ref = event.data.ref.parent; // reference to the items
  var now = Date.now();
  var cutoff = now - 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  var oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(cutoff);
  return oldItemsQuery.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    // create a map with all children that need to be removed
    var updates = {};
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      updates[child.key] = null
    });
    // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
    return ref.update(updates);
  });
});
```

Comment: It looks like you took code from [this example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-old-child-nodes), and then changed the first line. What do you now expect it to do? Did you debug it? Does the function get called when you expect it to? Did the query result in anything? What timestamp did it query?

Comment: What do you now expect it to do? each two hours, users with timestamp longer than 2 hrs will be removed..

I didn't debug it..
It got called but it didn't execute like i wanted(It did nothing)..
Database query wasn't empty as i added dummy data..
more than 2 hours..

Comment: The code you shared doesn't run automatically.  It only runs when somebody writes something to the database under `driversAvailable`. If nothing is written, old drivers won't be deleted.

Comment: Did you check the timestamp `cutoff`? Essentially: try to reproduce the problem with hardcoded values. I'd also recommend running the query outside of Cloud Functions first, just because it's faster to test things that way.

Comment: I tried making the cut off 1 minute (60 * 1000), and then i wrote in the database
https://i.imgur.com/3S2JU8R.png

but nothing happened